# No suitable request handler found

Tags: typo3

I try to redirect via TypoScript when a condition apply. Something like:

```
[globalString = IENV:REQUEST_URI = /page/]
   config >
   config.additionalHeaders = Location: /somepage/
[global]
```

But I get the error „No suitable request handler found“. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because you clear the entire `config.` object which leaves TYPO3 pretty much incapable of processing the request, or because `config.additionalHeaders` is an array and you convert it to a string (precisely, because this is TS, you actually change the type of the object itself to `Location: /somepage`). See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/7.6/Setup/Config/Index.html#additionalheaders for further information on how to add custom headers.

May I suggest instead that you configure such rules in your virtual host configuration or `.htaccess` file? That is usually a safer and more efficient solution when it concerns redirects!

Comment: Thanks. Clearing the config has evoked the error.
`[globalString = IENV:REQUEST_URI = /page/]` is only an example-condition ;-)